# How to add PNG resource in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resources, .net-assembly

I have a PNG (i.e. a compressed image) that I'd like to include in my assembly (i.e. application).

How to do it?

Additional information:

I tried adding a PNG resource to my assembly in Visual Studio 2010:

[image]

But that didn't work, as Visual Studio converts it to an uncompressed bitmap:

[image]

Except I want to add a PNG.

Otherwise [my 1MB application becomes 8MB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9314225/12597):

```
]=== 1MB file size ==>
]=== 8MB file size ==============================================================================================================================================>
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

1. Go to the project menu -> properties.
2. Select the resources tab
3. **Make sure Images is selected first.**
4. Click the arrow beside 'add resource'
5. New Image (Select from Image File Types)
6. Find the PNG

[image]

Comment: +1 Tried as you suggested and could reproduce that it works correct.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot showing the `Type` of the resource once added. i follow those steps and in my example a 131 kB PNG is converted to a 178 KB BMP.

Comment: @IanBoyd do you mean does mine convert to a bmp? No it does not. If you still want me to post the added resource I can though

Comment: This answer does not work. It tries to convert the PNG to a BMP file, but that fails too.

Comment: It doesn't convert it to a BMP for me, what verzion of visual studio are you using?

Comment: Did what you've suggested but the PNG files are still _not_ accessible using `Properties.Resources.<PNGfile>` =(

Comment: In VS 2022, this is done via opening the project's Resources.resx file directly, not via project menu -> properties.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could make this work, is by removing the file extension from the PNGs. That way Visual Studio doesn't recognize the files as images, and leaves them untouched.