# how to change background image of a form in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, background-image

Can I use Menu strip or context menu to allow the user so that he can change the background image of the window instead of background colour in c# ?

Comment: Yeah, yes you can.

Comment: @SoMoS How? can you please explain?

Comment: @dholakiyaankit I dont know how to do so..this is my first project..i need help

Comment: First of all add detailed explaination of your question then google it frist then try here this forum for http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: I am making an app for kids.. I want to give user the power of changing backgrounds according to the kid..if its a girl , parents can apply girly background images.. I want to add 5 background images for girls and 5 for boys  , and i dont know how to do so

Comment: iam a student n iam learning c#, this is a small project my teacher gave so that we can learn.. i have googled it but didnt find anything

Comment: @user3004295: how is that a teacher gives a project without pointing out resources to learn how to do it?

Comment: @SoMoS Iam not making any money, my project is almost ready.. my teacher said about changing the background colour, but i wana change background , thats it, if you know kindly help me.. i know how to add audio and images to resources, i know how to use audio, but i cnt figure out how to use image in context menu

Comment: teacher said to use our own ideas aswell.. n this is what i wana do, i do know about adding resources, making menus, teacher taught us ..

Answer (score 18):

You can use `MenuStrip` Control to change the `BackgroundImage` of the `Form`.

**Note:** Here i'm giving you the steps/idea so that you can change as per your requirements.but you need to Explore more.

**Steps:**

1.You add the `MenuStrip` control from `Menus & Toolbars` Category in `ToolBox` and then Add the `MenuStrip` To the `Form`.

2.You can add `Menu Items` as you want .ex: change Image1,change Image2 etc.,

3.You can handle the `MenuItemClick` Event to Change the `BackgroundImage` of the `Form`

**Sample Code:**

```
private void changeBGImageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Image myimage = new Bitmap(@"D:\Images\myImage1.jpg");
    this.BackgroundImage = myimage;
}
```

**Sample code2:**  accessing `Images` from `Resources` file.
Note: first you need to add the `Images` into `Resources`.
Here i have added `myImage1.jpg` file to `Resources`.

See here for [how to add images to Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316549/how-to-add-png-resource-in-visual-studio-2010)

```
this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.myImage1;
```

Please let me know if you need anything more.

Comment: awww it worked.. thank you so much :)  , but it will work on my system only, can i add images to resources and use them from there?

Comment: You are welcome :) , yes you can access from resources, if you need i can edit my answer with "how to access images from resources"

Comment: @user3004295: you can check my edited answer to know how to access images from Resources.

Comment: @user3004295: you can check my edited answer i have already done it.

Comment: First of all, thanks for this useful answer, but, is there any way to make the image as big as the window? In my case, the image is setted as background correctly, but it repeats

Answer (score 0):

1. every image you want use to background image form select in properties window again several once
2. Go into soluitionExproler to child Form1 open Form1.Designer.cs
3. copy this part of form Designer
   Form1.ActiveForm.BackgroundImage = global::TtimerComputer.Properties.Resources.ImageName;
4. paste into your wanted change ImageName

Example:

```
private void btnBackSilver_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Form1.ActiveForm.BackgroundImage = global::YourProjectName.Properties.Resources.ImageName1;
}

private void btnBackGreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Form1.ActiveForm.BackgroundImage = global::YourProjectName.Properties.Resources.ImageName2;
}
```