# How to embed png resource without visual studio converting to bitmap?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015.  When I add an existing .png file to my project's resources, VS recognizes it is an image and changes the format to a bitmap.  It changes the size and bytes.

This is really annoying since I need the exact original png, not some converted bitmap.  When I use c# to access my resource, e.g. Resources.MyPngFileName it returns the changed bitmap.  Does anyone know how to avoid this?

Comment: Why don't you just have it in the solution files, outside the resources?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add PNG resource in Visual Studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316549/how-to-add-png-resource-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: @Jdsfighter, yes, though the answer in VS2015 is to remove the extension.  The accepted answer for that question doesn't work.  If you'd like to answer I will accept

Comment: just upvote the answer that did work; thats how it is supposed to work

Comment: All pixel based images are bitmaps. Don't confuse this with the BMP format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 2015 (not the suggested duplicate answer for 2010) the only thing that works is to take off the .png extension and add as a file.  Then Visual Studio does not change the file.

Maybe they will change this in a future update to work like 2010