# How to add Image to tileItemElement in a tilecontrol Winforms without the GUI interface in the .NET framework

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress-windows-ui

```
tileItemElement5.ImageAlignment = DevExpress.XtraEditors.TileItemContentAlignment.TopCenter;
tileItemElement5.ImageScaleMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.TileItemImageScaleMode.ZoomInside;
tileItemElement5.ImageSize = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 135);
```

Here I want to assign an image to my `tileItemElement5`. I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for DevExpress WinForms, you can just assign an image directly to the TileItemElement.

`tileItemElement.Image = Properties.Resources.delete_icon;`

You can get the image from your Properties/Resources as I did in the short example, or load it in code.

Link to the [documentation](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.TileItemElement.Image) and a tip

DevExpress provides a very detailed documentation with lots of examples, I recommend that you utilize your search engine next time because 99% of the time, you will find an answer on their website.

Because DevExpress provides libraries for multiple platforms and frameworks, I recommend that you preface your search engine search with "DevExpress C# WinForm" then type in the issue or what you are looking for. This will make sure that you get results that match your development environment.

Comment: how do i import the image to the properties/resources folder?

Comment: You can follow this quick stack overflow post about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316549/how-to-add-png-resource-in-visual-studio-2010

Or in text. Go to your solution explorer, expand the project and find Properties, expand that and double click on Resources.resx. A new window in Visual Studio will open, click on the arrow next to Add resource, to bring down an menu then click on New Image

Comment: tanks man it worked... know i have to figur out fetching img from database. do you know how?

Comment: You will have to look around on stackoverflow for that or ask a new question